# Joining WordPress Comments with Post Titles from MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, join

I'm working with a wordpress database and need to get some data on the comments.

The goal is to get comments from a decommissioned site.  I have the database running on my local system and can generate a report from the wp_comments table easy enough.  That table has a column named 'comment_post_id' which is a direct correlation to the ID column in the wp_posts table.

I've dumped both from mysql into excel and done a vlookup from the comments table into the posts table to get the desired report.

While the dump->excel process works, I know this could probably be done with a query in mysql.

My first crack at it fails:

```
SELECT * FROM 'wp_posts' WHERE ('wp_comments.comment_post_id' = 'wp_posts.id');
```

and doesn't even include a join yet.

Can you provide any pointers or tips on getting a correct query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE id IN (SELECT comment_post_id FROM wp_comments);
```

or

```
SELECT A.* FROM wp_posts A INNER JOIN
(SELECT comment_post_id FROM wp_comments) B
ON A.id = B.comment_post_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your direction!  I flipped the wp_posts and wp_comments in the SELECT statements to get better visibility of the info I needed from the comments.  Here's the query I came up with: SELECT A.comment_ID, A.comment_post_id, B.id, B.post_title, A.comment_author, A.comment_author_email, A.comment_author_url, A.comment_date, A.comment_content, A.comment_approved, A.comment_type FROM `wp_comments` A INNER JOIN (SELECT id, post_title FROM wp_posts) B on A.comment_post_ID = B.id WHERE A.comment_approved NOT LIKE 'spam';